# why TextTheme doesn't change AppBar TextStyle?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-text

[image: Screenshot of the app]

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.dancingScriptTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,),
),
```

So as you can see I'm using dancingScriptTextTheme in my flutter app. But using this textTheme only changes the textSytle in the body of the app. The font in the AppBar remains unaffected as you can see in the screenshot. How can I also change the font of the the appBar? Explain in detail.

Comment: Appbar has its own text theme, try adding in the copyWith method appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(textTheme: //the textTheme you want)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply it to AppBar, you should define the text theme on AppBar's own textTheme as below:

```dart
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.dancingScriptTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      ),
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.dancingScriptTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
      ),
    ));
```